# INSERT query in PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am really new to PHP and am messing around with adding and editing database values. I have accomplished adding information to the database, but I cannot seem to figure out how to edit it properly!

I created a file called **edit.php** and here is the code I have thus far:

```
<?php

include '../database/connection.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];
$first_name = $_GET['first_name'];
$last_name = $_GET['last_name'];
$university_id = $_GET['university_id'];

$sql = "UPDATE master_roster (first_name, last_name, university_id) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$university_id') WHERE id = $id";

?>
```

No error messages of any help are posting. Whenever the form is submitted and is handed off to this file, I just get a blank screen with no results. I cannot seem to figure out what it is I am missing to have it update the content from input fields!

EDIT: I gave all of suggestions a shot but it still does not work! Here is the form that the data is coming from:

```
<?php 
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $first_name = $_GET['first_name'];
  $last_name = $_GET['last_name'];
  $university_id = $_GET['university_id'];

?>
<form action="edit_member.php?id=<?php echo $id; echo "&first_name="; echo $first_name; echo "&last_name="; echo $last_name; echo "&university_id="; echo $university_id; ?>" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>University ID</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="university_id" value="<?php echo $university_id; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I am not too concerned about SQL Injections at this point because I am just trying to learn the basics.

---

EDIT #2:

LIST.PHP - where the DB pulls all the members

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>University ID</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
  include '../database/connection.php';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM master_roster";
  if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['university_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='form.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "&first_name=" . $row['first_name'] . "&last_name=" . $row['last_name'] . "&university_id=" . $row['university_id'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
      }
      echo "</table>";
      mysqli_free_result($result); 
    } else {
      echo "No records matching your query were found."; 
    }
  } else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
  }
  mysqli_close($link);
  ?>
```

EDIT.PHP

```
<?php

include '../database/connection.php';

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
$university_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['university_id']);

$sql = "UPDATE master_roster 
SET 
    first_name = '$first_name', 
    last_name = '$last_name', 
    university_id = '$university_id'
WHERE 
    id = $id";
?>
```

FORM.PHP

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="last_name"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>University ID</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="university_id"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: *"INSERT query in PHP not working"* - yet you're using "UPDATE" which is a syntax error. I suggest you go back to the manuals.

Comment: Apart from that: just defining a string is not enough to execute a query against a database server...

Comment: YOUR QUERY IS WRONG.

Comment: Here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html being two different animals.

Comment: and the api to connect with is unknown and the GET arrays as to where they're coming from.

Comment: UPDATE works hand in hand with SET
`UPDATE tablename SET columnname = newvalue WHERE condition`

Comment: *"No error messages of any help are posting."* - That's because you didn't execute the query and you're not checking for errors. Once you do execute it, you **will* get an error, provided you "check" for errors, both via error reporting and the query.

Comment: `<form action="edit_member.php?id=<?php echo $id; echo "&first_name="; echo $first_name; echo "&last_name="; echo $last_name; echo "&university_id="; echo $university_id; ?>" method="post">` - OMG, what is that?

Answer (score 4):

This is the wrong syntax for [`update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html). `update` takes a series of `column=value` clauses:

```
UPDATE master_roster 
SET    first_name = '$first_name', 
       last_name = '$last_name', 
       university_id = '$university_id'
WHERE  id = $id
```

Mandatory comment:
Using variable substitutions in strings like that leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: In all fairness to the other answer, [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458232/insert-query-in-php-not-working#comment72059456_42458330) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458232/insert-query-in-php-not-working#comment72059498_42458330) also apply to this answer and should not be left out of the equation.

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for the help! I gave that a shot and put it inside $sql ="" but to no avail!

Answer (score 1):

You're writing wrong `UPDATE` statement.

Try this

```
$sql = "UPDATE master_roster 
SET 
    first_name = '$first_name', 
    last_name = '$last_name', 
    university_id = '$university_id'
WHERE 
    id = $id";
```

Now execute the query using statement below.

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

`$result` will return `true` if the insertion is successful and `false` if not.

Use this to check if it is done or not.

```
if($result == false){
    die( "Connection Failed: ".$conn->error );
}
```

You should also be prevented from SQL injection.
You can use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` method.

`$first_name = $_GET['first_name'];
 $safe_first_name =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $first_name);`

You can also use parameterized query.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

---

Now read the codes below modify your both pages like this.

> Form

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="first_name"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="last_name"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>University ID</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="university_id"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

> This will update the data.

```
<?php

include '../database/connection.php';

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last_name']);
$university_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['university_id']);

$sql = "UPDATE master_roster 
SET 
    first_name = '$first_name', 
    last_name = '$last_name', 
    university_id = '$university_id'
WHERE 
    id = $id";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result == false){
    die( "Connection Failed: ".$conn->error );
}

?>
```

Comment: this query will fail due to most probable string literals not being quoted. It needs to be modified.

Comment: SQL injection has nothing to do with that question.

Comment: @chris85 ^ that's for you ;-)

Comment: *"SQL injection has nothing to do with that question"* - ok, but string literals do.

Comment: ...but that's where you stand to be wrong. What if the username is `John O'Hare`? since the apostrophe is considered as an sql injection

Comment: Yeah right @Fred-ii-.
Let me modify my answer one more time.

Comment: I noticed the edit. You realize that `mysql_` does not intermix with the mysqli_ api.

Comment: And make sure write your variable in place of  `$conn`.

Comment: @Siraj Thanks again for those modifications! I attempted, once again but nothing is changing.

Comment: @Siraj I have literally copy/pasted everything you have posted but it still won't update. I went ahead and updated my original post to show ALL of my working files. I've been at this for hours but cannot seem to figure it out -- I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: @Siraj That's what the browser is throwing saying HTTP 500 Error, unable to handle this request.

Comment: This is not due to error in PHP. This is server error.

Comment: @Siraj the server handles PHP fine for all other apps.